# Regex in C# finding all foldernames containing [ | ]

Tags: c#, regex

Following Regex should be processed in C#:

I want to find all strings containing '[' or ']'.

And it should match in following strings;

```
...an folder ] ...
...and ] another...
...[so] this is...
...and [ a few more]...
...lorem ipsum[...
```

following code wont compile:

```
string pattern ="\.*(\[|\])\.*";
List<string> directoriesMatchingPattern=  Util.GetSubFoldersMatching(attachmentDirectory,pattern);
```

And the implementation:

```
     public static List<string> GetSubFoldersMatching(string attachmentDirectory, string pattern)
        {
            List<string> matching = new List<string>();
            foreach (string directoryName in Directory.GetDirectories(attachmentDirectory))
            {
                Match match = Regex.Match(directoryName, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                if (match.Success)
                {
                    matching.Add(directoryName);
                }
                else
                {
                    matching.AddRange(GetSubFoldersMatching(directoryName,pattern));
                }
            }
            return matching;
        }
```

The Error shown by Visual Studio is:

```
Error   Unrecognized escape sequence
```

How to fix this, or how to escape this chars correctily? googling arround wasn't helpful at all.

Comment: Since a regex will by default match anywhere within a string, there's no real need for the `.*` at the start and end of your pattern. The following should work fine: `string pattern = @"[\[\]]";`

Answer (score 5):

Escape the pattern string:

```
string pattern ="\\.*(\\[|\\])\\.*";
```

Or:

```
string pattern = @"\.*(\[|\])\.*";
```

For a more indepth look into strings and string escape sequences look here on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362.aspx).

Comment: Note that the bracketing `\.*`s are useless in this scenario and that `(\[|\])` can also be written as the arguably simpler `[[\]]`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [verbatim strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) to make escaping make more sense for regexes. I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the `\.*`, but `Match` works on matching just a portion of it by default, so I don't think it's necessary. I'd use the following pattern:

```
@"(\[|\])"
```

For improved performance, create a [`Regex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object instead of using the static `Regex` method (since you're reusing the pattern). And you don't need to specify `IgnoreCase`, since you don't care about letters here, just the `[]` symbols.

```
Regex myRegex = new Regex(@"(\[|\])");
// later, in loop
Match match = myRegex.Match(directoryName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on from Tim S.'s answer, you could create `GetSubFoldersMatching` as an overloaded function so that you can either pass it an existing `Regex` object or a string and it will deal with it. By reusing the `Regex` object you should also get a slight performance increase.

```
public static List<String> GetSubFoldersMatching(String attachmentDirectory, String pattern)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
    return GetSubFoldersMatching(attachmentDirectory, regex);
}

public static List<String> GetSubFoldersMatching(String attachmentDirectory, Regex regex)
{
    List<String> matching = new List<String>();
    foreach (String directoryName in Directory.GetDirectories(attachmentDirectory))
    {
        Match match = regex.Match(directoryName);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            matching.Add(directoryName);
        }
        else
        {
            matching.AddRange(GetSubFoldersMatching(directoryName, regex));
        }
    }
    return matching;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the @ in front of your pattern:

```
string pattern =@"\.*(\[|\])\.*";
```

and it will work.

Here is an example of the whole thing.

```
        List<string>  n = new List<string>();
        n.AddRange( new string[] { "an folder ] ",
            "and ] another",
            "not this one",
            "[so] this is",
            "and [ a few more]",
            "OR num2 either",
            "lorem ipsum["});

        string pattern =@"(\[|\])"; // you don't need your \.* parts
        List<string> directoriesMatchingPattern = new List<string>();
        foreach (string d in n)
        {
            if (Regex.Match(d, pattern).Success)
            {
                directoriesMatchingPattern.Add(d);
            }
        }
```